# Given $g \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ Study derivability of $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}$

Tags: derivatives

Given $g \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ ($g$ is a function twice derivable), with $g(0)=0$. consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x}\:\:\:\:\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^*, \:\:\:\:f(0)=g'(0)
$$

Study the derivability of $\:f$ and the continuity of its derivative.

Would it be true that $\:f$ is derivable in $\mathbb{R}\:/\:0$? That is all real numbers but $0$. And is there even a difference in the derivability of $f$ and the continuity of its derivative?

Answer (score 0):

this is my reasoning, by an inexperienced student of sciences.

Maybe it's wrong, but perhaps it will serve as inspiration.

Before we can derive the function $f(x)$ we have to study her continuity.

She's continuous for each $x\neq 0$, for $x=0$ we have to find:

$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$$

You can easily verify that the limit is infinite if $g(0)\neq 0$ and is $f(0)$ if $g(0)=0$; in this last case, $f$ is continuous in $0$ too.

$$f'(x)=\frac{xg'(x)-g(x)}{x^2}$$

Now, this is continuous again for each $x\neq 0$.

What do you think will happen for $x\to 0$?